# Unir vários arquivos parquet

Tags: python, powerbi

Tenho vários arquivos .parquet baixados do PySUS, preciso unificá-los para importar no Power BI.

```
from pysus.ftp.databases.sia import SIA
sia = SIA().load() #Localizando arquivos DATASUS

sia

sia.metadata

sia.groups

print(str(len(sia.get_files(["BI"]))) + " files") #Escolhendo o grupo

sia.get_files("BI", uf="GO", year=2021) #Escolha o grupo, estado e o ano

files = sia.get_files("BI", uf="PE", year=2023, month=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]) #Escolha o grupo, estado e o ano
files

sia.describe(files[0])

sia.download(files) #Aguarde o download

import pandas as pd

parquet_doc = '/root/pysus/BIGO2105.parquet' #Insira o nome do arquivo gerado

df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_doc)

df.head() #Nao precisa executar

csv_output = '/root/pysus/exportacao_BI_05_2021.csv' #Escolha o nome do arquivo a ser exportado

df.to_csv(csv_output, index=False) #Converte em csv

df = pd.read_csv(csv_output) #Leitura

df.columns.values #exibir as clunas
```